# Upload Zip Folder to Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-data-management

We upload many small (1kb) text files one at a time to the Data Management API, and the latency becomes a real issue as the number increases.

Is it possible to upload a zipped folder containing several text files, and have the individual files appear inside a single folder in BIM 360?

Ideally we could compress the files into a single zip folder, upload this package once and have the Data Management API extract all the files into a BIM 360 folder.

Comment: A manifest of the individual item ids and version ids would be needed as a response to this REST request.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I don't believe it is possible to upload a zipped folder and have the API extract all the individual files once the upload finishes. I have asked our DM API engineers but keep in mind that Autodesk is currently close for the Holiday week. Most likely I will hear back from them after Jan 2nd. Thank you for your patience and collaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JaimeRosales. I'll look forward to an answer in the new year :-)

Comment: @JaimeRosales, have you had a chance to discuss this with our colleagues at Autodesk?